# $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a non-constant entire function then every line which passes through origin would intersect image(f)?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a non-constant entire function then how to prove or disprove that every line which passes through origin would intersect image(f)?

Can anyone please  give me a hint?

Comment: Image can miss at most one point in the plane like exponential and zero; the proof for entire lines, actually even rays is trivial as you can arrange the missed ray to be the negative reals by a rotation, use a simple conformal equivalence to send it to the unit disk and use liouville

Comment: Do you want a proof that avoid to use Picard’s theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is of course the great Picard theorem that says that $\mathbb{C}-f(\mathbb{C})$ contains at most one point (!) so the statement is definitely true; However, this is an overkill (it is a difficult theorem to prove).

Suppose that $f(\mathbb{C})$ does not intersect some line passing through the origin. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, we have that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is a subset of one of the two half-planes that the line defines; If you formulate your problem correctly (e.g. start by supposing that this line is the y-axis) and consider a new entire function, you can get to a contradiction by using Liouville's theorem. This is my hint!